# Show that $\rho : X \times X \mapsto \mathbb{R} $ is continuous function on $(X \times X, \tau)$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity

Show that $\rho : X \times X \mapsto \mathbb{R} $ is continuos function on $(X \times X, \tau)$ where $\tau ((x_1,x_2), (y_1,y_2)) = \sqrt{\rho (x_1-y_1)^2 + \rho (x_2-y_2)^2}$ and $X \times X$ is the product of two metric space.

Proof let $\{x_n,y_n\}$ be a sequence that converges to $(x,y)$. every sequence that converges in a metric space is cauchy hence $\{x_n,y_n\}$ is cauchy. Now i need to show that $\rho (x_n,y_n) \rightarrow \rho(x,y)$

since $\{x_n,y_n\}$ is cauchy in $X \times X$
then we can say that $(x_n) \rightarrow x$ and $(y_n) \rightarrow y$ for $ \epsilon > 0$ then $|x_n-x| < \epsilon/2$ and $|y_n-y| < \epsilon/2$
for some reason I do not think this right. Is that the right approach so far

Comment: What do you mean by $\rho\colon X\times X\rightarrow \mathbb R$, and what is the $\rho$ in the definition of $\tau$?

Comment: $ \rho$ is a metric space

Comment: Do you mean $\rho(x_1, x_2)^2$ instead of $\rho(x_1 - x_2)^2$? Or is the space normed and $\rho$ is a norm?